# Cannot set properties of undefined when connecting to mongodb with mongoose. NextJS Typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

In this code i'm tryng to connect to a mongodb with mongoose:
file: app/utils/db.ts

```
import connect from "@/app/utils/db.ts";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import endpointsConfig from '@/endpoints.config';
dotenv.config();
const uri = endpointsConfig.mongoUri?.toString() ?? ''
console.log("pre uri log")
console.log(uri)
console.log("post uri log")
const connect = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("inside try")
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://mooddb:VgHS7TnBQm7ehcN@mood-recorder.ejrj9ja.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("inside catch")
    throw new Error("Connection failed!");
  }
};

export default connect;
```

This is the api for where i want to use the mongo connection
with just a test to see if it work
file: app/api/auth/register.ts

```
import connect from "@/app/utils/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const POST = async (req : any) =>{
    const {test} = await req.json();
    await connect(); //I think that's the line

    return new NextResponse(test)
}
```

Here is where i call the api:

app/components/RegistrationForm.tsx

```
  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    // You can perform further validation or submit the form data here
    console.log(formData);
    if (
      formData.email === formData.confirmEmail &&
      formData.password == formData.confirmPassword
    ) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/auth/register", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            formData,
          }),
        });
        res.status === 201;
        console.log("fetch sent");
      } catch (err: any) {
        setError(err);
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

the code here is the submit handler of a registration form, please don take care of the controls because is just some test to solve the error i'm getting.

When i compile the form and the submitHandler is called i get the following error:

```
error - [rendering] [root of the server]/api/auth/register
  Error during SSR Rendering
  error rendering: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'base')

  Debug info:
  - error rendering: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'base')
        at new Mongoose (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:102:25) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:85301:32]
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1278:45) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:85608:45]
        [at [project]/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js (ecmascript, ssr) (C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:85612:3)]
        at /turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:332:21 [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:253:27]
        at runModuleExecutionHooks (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:381:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:286:9]
        at instantiateModule (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:331:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:252:9]
        at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:429:10) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:313:12]
        at commonJsRequire (/turbopack/[turbopack]/shared/runtime-utils.ts:152:18) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:83:20]  
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/index.js:8:18) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:85616:18]
        [at [project]/node_modules/mongoose/index.js (ecmascript, ssr) (C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:85665:3)]
        at /turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:332:21 [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:253:27]
        at runModuleExecutionHooks (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:381:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:286:9]
        at instantiateModule (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:331:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:252:9]
        at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:429:10) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:313:12]
        at esmImport (/turbopack/[turbopack]/shared/runtime-utils.ts:142:18) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:74:20]        
        [at C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:99135:117]
        [at [project]/app/utils/db.ts (ecmascript, ssr) (C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:99153:3)]
        at /turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:332:21 [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:253:27]
        at runModuleExecutionHooks (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:381:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:286:9]
        at instantiateModule (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:331:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:252:9]
        at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:429:10) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:313:12]
        at esmImport (/turbopack/[turbopack]/shared/runtime-utils.ts:142:18) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:74:20]        
        [at C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:99159:102]
        [at [project]/app/api/auth/register/route.ts (ecmascript, ssr) (C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\_bbca61._.js:99170:3)]
        at /turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:332:21 [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:253:27]
        at runModuleExecutionHooks (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:381:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:286:9]
        at instantiateModule (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:331:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:252:9]
        at getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:429:10) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:313:12]
        at esmImport (/turbopack/[turbopack]/shared/runtime-utils.ts:142:18) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:74:20]        
        [at C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_d0376b._.js:13:123]
        [at [next]/entry/app/route.ts/(ROUTE_MODULE)/[project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js (ecmascript)/(ENTRY)/[project]/app/api/auth/register/route.ts (ecmascript)/(BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG)/[project]/app/api/auth/register/route.ts/bootstrap-config.ts (ecmascript) (ecmascript, ssr) (C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_d0376b._.js:62:3)]
        at /turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:332:21 [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:253:27]
        at runModuleExecutionHooks (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:381:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:286:9]
        at instantiateModule (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:331:5) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:252:9]
        at getOrInstantiateRuntimeModule (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:1287:10) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:859:12]
        at Object.registerChunk (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/nodejs/runtime-backend-nodejs.ts:86:11) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:952:21]
        at registerChunk (/turbopack/[turbopack]/dev/runtime/base/runtime-base.ts:1341:18) [C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:896:20]
        [at <anonymous>]
        [at C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:989:18]
        [at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_a47e86._.js:990:3)]
        [at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)]
        [at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)]
        [at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)]
        [at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)]
        [at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)]
        [at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)]
        [at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maga\Documents\mood-project\mood-test\.next\server\app\chunks\ssr\[next]_entry_app_route_ts_72d03f._.js:11:1)]
        [at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)]
        [at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)]
        [at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)]
        [at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)]
        [at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)]
        [at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47]

[500] /api/auth/register (522ms)
```

I'm using:

- next 13.4.7
- typescript 5.1.3
- node 19.8.1
- mongoose 7.3.1

Using turbopack.

I need to connect to the database and register a new user but i still get this error every time i try to use the mongoose connection.

Comment: Why are you importing `import connect from "@/app/utils/db.ts"` inside the `/app/utils/db.ts` file? Did you mean to import something else instead?

Comment: I think that i didn't mean tò write that line i'm gonna check later when im at home. In the mean time i switched to mongo default driver and not using mongoose.. without turbopack i Got a loro of other errors Always related to mongoose and ita dependencies